# How can generate the jacoco report from Android studio and export it to sonarqube, as am getting the code coverage as zero(jacoco+gradle+sonarqube)

Tags: java, kotlin-android-extensions

> ```
> INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.3.0.2102/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
> INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
> INFO: SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102
> INFO: Java 12.0.1 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
> INFO: Mac OS X 10.15.6 x86_64
> INFO: User cache: /Users/fenix2/.sonar/cache
> INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.3.0.2102/libexec/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
> INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
> INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.4.1
> INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
> INFO: Load global settings
> INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=55ms
> INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXNnOo1V8h5sJwwrOZcS
> INFO: User cache: /Users/fenix2/.sonar/cache
> INFO: Load/download plugins
> INFO: Load plugins index
> INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=33ms
> INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=112ms
> INFO: Process project properties
> INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=6ms
> INFO: Execute project builders
> INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=2ms
> INFO: Project key: FenixGoNative
> INFO: Base dir: /Users/fenix2/Documents/LatestGo/FenixGoNative
> INFO: Working dir: /Users/fenix2/Documents/LatestGo/FenixGoNative/.scannerwork
> INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'FenixGoNative'
> INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'FenixGoNative' (done) | time=36ms
> INFO: Load quality profiles
> INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=170ms
> INFO: Load active rules
> INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=2143ms
> INFO: Indexing files...
> INFO: Project configuration:
> INFO: 1105 files indexed
> INFO: 7825 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
> INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
> INFO: Quality profile for kotlin: Sonar way
> INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
> INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module FenixGoNative
> INFO: Load metrics repository
> INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=13ms
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
> ```
>
> (file:/Users/fenix2/.sonar/cache/52f5340dd05620cd162e2b9a45a57124/sonar-javascript-plugin.jar)
> to method
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
> INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): none
> INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
> WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can
> be provided using sonar.java.libraries property.
> INFO: JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=3ms
> INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization
> INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=0ms
> INFO: Java Main Files AST scan
> INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
> INFO: Load project repositories
> INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=349ms
> INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
> INFO: Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=1104ms
> INFO: Java Test Files AST scan
> INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
> INFO: Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=1ms
> INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
> INFO: Java Generated Files AST scan
> INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
> INFO: Java Generated Files AST scan (done) | time=0ms
> INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
> INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=1242ms
> INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily]
> INFO: No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.
> INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=12ms
> INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
> WARN: No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='presentation/build/test-results/testTrainDebugUnitTest,data/build/test-results/testTrainDebugUnitTest'.
> Using default locations:
> target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
> INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
> INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=9ms
> INFO: Sensor Kotlin Sensor [kotlin]
> INFO: 689 source files to be analyzed
> INFO: Sensor Kotlin Sensor [kotlin] (done) | time=4008ms
> INFO: 689/689 source files have been analyzed
> INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
> INFO: parsing [/Users/fenix2/Documents/LatestGo/FenixGoNative/target/surefire-reports]
> INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
> INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
> INFO: 277 source files to be analyzed
> INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=807ms
> INFO: 277/277 source files have been analyzed
> INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
> INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=4ms
> INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
> INFO: 277 source files to be analyzed
> INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=667ms
> INFO: 277/277 source files have been analyzed
> INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
> INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
> INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=108ms
> INFO: Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer
> INFO: Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=11ms
> INFO: CPD Executor 283 files had no CPD blocks
> INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 406 files
> INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=105ms
> INFO: Analysis report generated in 388ms, dir size=2 MB
> INFO: Analysis report compressed in 1937ms, zip size=1 MB
> INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 67ms
> INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=FenixGoNative
> INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
> INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXN8GyF5zYWRg-xjPnW4
> INFO: Analysis total time: 16.702 s
> INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
> INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> INFO: Total time: 17.542s
> INFO: Final Memory: 18M/74M
> INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------